# Trying to get BCC in ElectronCash - but after priv keys import - empty wallet

Tags: client, ecash

I exported the private keys from Electrum, where I had BTC.
Then I send these BTC to a different wallet.
Then I tried to import these keys in Electron Cash. It worked, but the wallet is empty.

Any idea what I did wrong? What can I do now?

===
UPDATE

I tried to import all my priv keys to Bitcoint ABC.
WIth each priv key I imported a rescan took place, so it took 2-3 days to import all the priv keys (after rescan "null" appeared). However my balance is still zero.

I then imported the address in which there should be funds. And yes, the funds appeared, however in "watch-only". Not spendable.

If I try to re-import the key for this address I get null.
If I try to import the key with the **true** parameter, still I get immediately true without any new rescan.

If I check this address in blockchair.com I see that the funds are still there and not spent. There is a blue X on "spent?" column.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if its related, but there's a [warning](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt) about Electron Cash on the Electrum website. From that article... "The person who distributes the Electron Cash binaries has decided to remain anonymous, and uses the fake name "Jonald Fyookball" in order to sign Electron Cash binaries. Thus, if these binaries contain code that is designed to steal your bitcoins, the author of the theft will be anonymous and walk away safely with your funds."

Comment: Make sure that you are connected to Electron Cash servers, not the normal Electrum servers. This continues to be a problem for Electron Cash as it can't distinguish between which servers use the chain that it wants to use.

Comment: @AndrewChow unfortunately I tried to connect it to different server with BCC and electroncash in their names.... it connects, but the BCC don't appear...

Comment: I would be very suspicious about the ElectronCash application. There have been multiple reports of users now whose BCC have been stolen. Where did you download the application?

Comment: from the official website, and also checked the hash before installing. So the app seems to be genuine. Really strange the stolen in so fast time. I undestand that I import they keys, I see the BCC in the balance, and then after some time they disappear.... but they didn't appear at all.

Comment: I added an update to the question. I tried with Bitcoin ABC